# C# unit testing public properties's namespace cannot be resolved in test calss

Tags: c#, unit-testing, namespaces

I am setting up a unit test project, and am having a weird issue. I can reference my project that the test project is for just fine. I can use objects from the project just fine. The problem is when I am trying to create public properties inside a unit test class, that are objects of the project being tested, the test class then errors saying it cannot resolve the type. I do not understand why that would be. I can better explain through an example below:

The reference below when in the method resolves fine, and builds.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Testing the default constructor for FundingAccount.cs
    /// </summary>
    public void ConstructorsTest_Default()
    {
        bool success = true;
        try
        {
            P.Web.Billing.Funding testFundingAccount = new P.Web.Billing.Funding();

            //was MessageColelction initialized during default constructor
            Assert.IsTrue(testFundingAccount.MessageCollection != null);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            success = false;
        }

        Assert.IsTrue(success == true);
    }
```

However, when I try to create a public property in the unit test class, so I can set it in the test class init method to use globally, it cannot resolve the namespace or type?

```
[TestClass]
public class FundingAccountTest
{
    #region Initialize and Control Flow method(s)

    //this causes error. [The namesppace or type 'P' could not be found
    public P.Web.Billing.Funding TestFundingAccount { get; set; }
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here? Thanks, and happy coding!

Comment: Both code samples are in the same file but one generates an error and one doesn't?  There's something you're not telling us.

Comment: If I use the namespace as a Public Property in the unit test class, it fails. But not when i use it in a method.

Comment: I'm not 'hiding' something or anything, I am confused on why that is. I have it referenced obviously because it works in a method. Just not when I try to use the type as a property in the test class. SO i wasn't sure if you are not suppose to have public properties with getters and setters in a unit test class or something maybe? Sounds wierd, but that is why I am also confused

Comment: That shouldn't be an error - port the _entire class_ (at least include the method and the attempt at a property.  If the namespace is reachable from the method it will be reachable from the property as well.

Comment: I'm agreeing with @DStanley, thus i would suggest you to do something different like Restart your VS.

Comment: I didn't meant to imply that you were "hiding" - what I meant that was _as posted_ your code should work fine, so there's something else going on that's not obvious from your information.

Comment: No, I also didn't mean that in sarcastic way. Sorry, typing comes out bad sometimes.  lol

Comment: I will try restarting and such. So I am not crazy at least. lol it just didn't make sense to me. I feel there is an unknown error somewhere else, causing the build not fail like that. Making it misleading due to not fully build the reference resource or something. I will try a few things, and update what the problem was if I correct it. Thanks everyone for the time.

Comment: So, they are using a tool called ILMerge, and was not aware of that. I was adding references, and through the build would be fine. BUt randomly fail. Was just a wierd quark.